# System.Net.HttpWebRequest does not contain a definition for ServercertificateValidationCallback

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, clr

I'm trying to compile followed class:

```
public partial class CLRTest
{
     [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
     public static void TestApi()
     {
          Uri  uri = new Uri("https://wrong.host.badssl.com/");
          HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
          request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += Validator;
          ...
     }

     public static bool Validator (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)

     {
          return true;
     }     
}
```

and getting error `System.Net.HttpWebRequest does not contain a definition for ServerCertificateValidationCallback`. How to fix it?

P.S. In console app I had no such error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with `ServicePointManager`, because `HttpWebRequest` inherits property `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` from it.

```
public partial class CLRTest
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString TestApi(SqlString url)
    {
        IgnoreBadCertificates();
        Uri uri = new Uri(url.ToString());
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            using (Stream receive = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(receive, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                return stream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static void IgnoreBadCertificates()
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
    }

    private static bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, X509Certificate certification, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```